# how to speed up and optimize mysql search with indexes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I need to optimize performance on a search with lots of strings like `Z1719121`.

my table structure:

```
codfabrica  => varchar 191 => nullable
codoriginal => varchar 191 => nullable
aplicacao   => mediumText  => nullable
```

table indexes:

```
codfabrica  => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation A    | cardinality 42466
codoriginal => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation A    | cardinality 7449
aplicacao   => non_unique 1 | seq_in_index 1 | collation NULL | cardinality 42550
```

laravel query code:

```
$allKeys = [...]; // array with lots of strings
$q = MyModel::query();
$q->whereIn('codfabrica', $allKeys);
$q->orWhereIn('codoriginal', $allKeys);
$q->orWhereRaw('MATCH (aplicacao) AGAINST (?)', array($allKeys));
```

results:

```
array with 1000 strings => took 5 seconds
array with 2500 strings => took 35 seconds
```

Is there any way I can optimize this search?

I am not experienced with INDEX, so did I created indexes correct way?

This table currently has `42.000 rows` and `20mb total size`, hosted on `AWS db.t3.small` RDS server (2 vCPUs, 2 GiB of memory).

Comment: Take a look at the documentation to learn about the `EXPLAIN` feature MySQL offers. It allows a detailed insight into how the storage engine uses existing indexes. And by that also if changing or adding indexes helps further.

Comment: More suited for [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is more or less limited to one index per table reference in a given query. You used `OR` terms in your search, and any one of them will use an index, but the others cannot. So the query must do a table-scan.

You can work around this by querying the table three times, each with a different search term, and that search will use the best index. This counts as three different table references, so a different index can be employed for each case.

Then `UNION` the results.

```
SELECT ... FROM MyModel WHERE codfabrica IN (...)
UNION
SELECT ... FROM MyModel WHERE codoriginal IN (...)
UNION
SELECT ... FROM MyModel WHERE MATCH (aplicacao) AGAINST (...)
```

I don't use the Laravel query builder, but it seems it does support `UNION`. Read https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#unions for examples.

Also I don't think you can pass an array to `MATCH()/AGAINST()`. I suggest you read about fulltext search expressions.

Comment: splitting query was a good method. thanks!